# How to choose SDK version Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

I've Visual Studio 2013 installed on my Windows 8.1 machine. Also the Windows Phone 7.1, 8.0 and 8.1 SDK's are installed.

When I make a new project, Visual Studio automatically make it a Windows Phone 8.1 project, I don't get the "Choose Target-version"-screen.

How can I make a Windows Phone 8.0 project in Visual Studio 2013?

Thanks.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2013 do you have installed exactly?  Have you installed VS 2013 Update 2?

Comment: @ ChuckWalbourn : I've installed VS 2013 Ultimate Update 2 (version 12.0.30501.00 update 2)

Comment: @Rick , you are on Windows 8.1.  I'm looking for this same question in the context of Windows 7.  So far, can't tell anything.  I'm writing for the desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a project using the *New Project* window of Visual Studio, choose one of the project types marked as *Windows Phone Silverlight* (for example, *Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)*. These project types are listed below the "standard" Windows Phone projects.

[image]

When choosing a Windows Phone Silverlight project, you'll be presented the *Target Windows Phone OS Version* window that allows you to set the SDK version to 8.0.

Comment: What's the difference between with and without Silverlight?

Comment: Windows Phone 7.x and 8.0 are based on Silverlight, while Windows Phone 8.1 uses the WinRT API. This means if you choose to create a WP 8.1 app you can make use of the same APIs as in Windows 8 Apps (and even build Apps for Windows Phone and Windows 8), but the Apps will not run on WP 7.x and WP 8.0. If you choose a Silverlight app, you need to use the "old" Silverlight APIs and the app will run on WP 7.x, 8.0, and 8.1 (but not on Windows 8).